# Comment particular lines using regular expression and sed

Tags: grep, csh, pcregrep

I have a very big verilog file(~350 MiB). In that, I want to comment particular module names.So i took a sample file and tried my regular expression on it.

Sample file(abc) :-

```
module util_minor_rev_id(minor_rev);
 output [3:0] minor_rev;
 wire [3:0] minor_rev;
 wire n_15, n_16, n_17, n_18, n_19, n_20, n_21, n_22;
 HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id0(.A (1'b1), .Z
      (minor_rev[0]));
 HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
      (minor_rev[1]));
xyz
HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
      (minor_rev[2]));
HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
      (minor_rev[3]));
endmodule
```

I want to comment the lines containing `HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z` till `;` so the output should be like

```
module util_minor_rev_id(minor_rev);
 output [3:0] minor_rev;
 wire [3:0] minor_rev;
 wire n_15, n_16, n_17, n_18, n_19, n_20, n_21, n_22;
/*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id0(.A (1'b1), .Z
     (minor_rev[0]));*/
/*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
     (minor_rev[1]));*/
xyz
/*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
      (minor_rev[2]));*/
/*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
      (minor_rev[3]));*/
endmodule
```

I am first trying to verify my pattern using regular expression and grep. I had problem using multi line pattern search. So i googled and found that `pcregrep` is my buddy.

```
pcregrep -Mno '^\s\*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z.*(\n|.)+;$' abc
```

But the output is:-

```
5:  HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id0(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[0]));
  HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[1]));
xyz
HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[2]));
  HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[3]));
7:  HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[1]));
xyz
HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[2]));
  HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[3]));
10:HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[2]));
  HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[3]));
12:  HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
       (minor_rev[3]));
```

I think its first matching from 5th line to last `;`. Then, 7th line to last `;`(semicolon). Then, 10th line to last `;`. And then 12th line to last `;`

How do I make it work as I want?

Answer (score 1):

Use non-greedy matching:

```
pcregrep -Mno '^\s*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z.*(\n|.)*?;$' file
```

Output:

```
5:      HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id0(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[0]));
7:      HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[1]));
10:HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[2]));
12:      HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[3]));
```

You can also comment the lines with Vim:

```
:%s!^\s*\zsHS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z\_.\{-};$!/* & */!
```

Result:

```
module util_minor_rev_id(minor_rev);
    output [3:0] minor_rev;
    wire [3:0] minor_rev;
    wire n_15, n_16, n_17, n_18, n_19, n_20, n_21, n_22;
    /* HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id0(.A (1'b1), .Z
        (minor_rev[0])); */
    /* HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
        (minor_rev[1])); */
xyz
/* HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
        (minor_rev[2])); */
    /* HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
        (minor_rev[3])); */
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using GNU sed

This seems to comment out the lines that you want:

```
sed -z 's|HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z[^;]*;|/*&*/|g' abc
```

For example:

```
$ sed -z 's|HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z[^;]*;|/*&*/|g' abc
module util_minor_rev_id(minor_rev);
      output [3:0] minor_rev;
      wire [3:0] minor_rev;
      wire n_15, n_16, n_17, n_18, n_19, n_20, n_21, n_22;
      /*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id0(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[0]));*/
      /*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[1]));*/
xyz
/*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[2]));*/
      /*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[3]));*/
    endmodule
```

The `-z` option (GNU only) tells sed to read the file in not a line at a time but until it finds a NUL character.  Since sensible text files never have a NUL character, this has the effect of reading in the whole file at once.

The above uses a single substitute command to put `/*` and `*/` around the lines of interest.

To change the file in-place:

```
sed -i.bak -z 's|HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z[^;]*;|/*&*/|g' abc
```

#### Using other sed

For BSD/OSX or other sed:

```
sed '/HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z/{:a; /;/{bb}; N; ba; :b; s|H|/*H|; s|;|;*/|;}' abc
```

For example:

```
$ sed '/HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z/{:a; /;/{bb}; N; ba; :b; s|H|/*H|; s|;|;*/|;}' abc
module util_minor_rev_id(minor_rev);
      output [3:0] minor_rev;
      wire [3:0] minor_rev;
      wire n_15, n_16, n_17, n_18, n_19, n_20, n_21, n_22;
      /*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id0(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[0]));*/
      /*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id1(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[1]));*/
xyz
/*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id2(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[2]));*/
      /*HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z opt_plug_minor_rev_id3(.A (1'b1), .Z
           (minor_rev[3]));*/
    endmodule
```

To change a file in-place:

```
sed -i.bak '/HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z/{:a; /;/{bb}; N; ba; :b; s|H|/*H|; s|;|;*/|;}' abc
```

Limitation: Since none of these sed commands parse your file, there may be situations where they do the wrong thing.

#### How it works

- `/HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z/{...}`

  This selects lines that contain `HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z` and, for those lines, the commands inside the curly braces are performed.  These commands are described below.
- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `/;/{bb}`

  If the pattern space currently contains `;`, then branch to label `b`.
- `N`

  Read in the next line from the file and store it in the pattern space.
- `ba`

  Branch to label `a`.
- `:b`

  This defines label `b`.
- `s|H|/*H|; s|;|;*/|;`

  If we get to here, that means that the pattern space starts with a line that contains `HS55_LH_OPTALL_GND_Z` and ends with a line that contains `;`.  For this pattern space, we put a `/*` in front of the first `H` and a `*/` after the first `;`.